# How to select a child element based on a value without regard to ordering and not using a FOR loop in XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The question is pretty big :) But this is what I want to achieve.

I am looping over every parent element(employee) and then looping over every child element of the parent(dependent) and need to match them together using a 3rd element called Election based on whether the dependent id(Dep_ID) matches in two separate rows.

So the xml is like:

```
<Employee>
 <Dependent><Depedent_ID>101</Depedent_ID> </Dependent>
 <Dependent><Depedent_ID>102</Depedent_ID> </Dependent>
 <Dependent><Depedent_ID>103</Depedent_ID> </Dependent>
 <Election Status="Current">       
  <Dependent> 
   <Dep_ID @id=102/>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent> 
   <Dep_ID @id=103/>
  </Dependent>
 </Election> 
  <Election Status="Previous">
  <Dependent> 
    <Dep_ID @id=103/>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent> 
   <Dep_ID @id=102/>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent> 
   <Dep_ID @id=101/>
  </Dependent>
 </Election>
</Employee>
```

So the exact question is for each dependent, see if he was there in the previous election but not in the current election.

My existing code is acting as if it is checking only the first dependent.
For example:
I need a way to write a xpath expression to first check if any of the Dep_Ids in the Previous Elections element equals 100 and then check if 100 is not equal to the Dep_Ids in the Current Elections. But the existing code checks on the first element. How to make my code check all of the child "Dependent" elements in the "Election" element?

I am sure it is something simple but I am not able to get it.

My existing code is:(Im looping over the child Dependent element of the employee element at this point)

```
<xsl:if test="parent::*/wd:Benefit_Elections[(wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor='Previous')]/wd:Benefit_Dependents/wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID']=wd:Dep_ID">
   <xsl:if test="count(parent::*/wd:Benefit_Elections[wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor='Current'] /wd:Benefit_Dependents)=0 or parent::*/wd:Benefit_Elections[wd:Coverage_Type='Medical/Vision' and (wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor='Current')]/wd:Benefit_Dependents/wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID']!=wd:Dep_ID">
```

**UPDATE**
Dimitre asked me to simplify/indent the above code for better readability.
As I said before I have two  statements in which these checks need to be made. I am open to using one  statement too but I am not getting this to work.

At this point, the code is looping over every child Dependent element of an Employee element. The code is then looping over the "Benefit Elections" element of the parent Employee element and is checking whether the current Dependent ID is equal to any of the child Dependent Ids of the benefit election element with status as "previous". This is not working in all cases as this check happens only for the first dependent element of "benefit elections".

**Simplified code of my  statement:**
I am within a  loop looping over every Employee/Dependent at this point.

```
<xsl:if test=
 "parent::*/Election[(Status='Previous')] 
                             /Dependent/Dep_ID/@id=Depedent_ID">
  <!--  DO SOMETHING HERE if above condition is true but this is checking only the first "Dependent element.-->
```

So my question is really: "In the above  statement, how can I check whether Dependent_ID is equal to ANY of the parent's Election/Dependent/Dep_ID/@id's? 
I hope this makes the question clear. Thanks.

**So again as an example I want this if condition to return TRUE when checking for Depedent_ID = 101, because 101 is not present in the current election but was present in the previous election.**

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression - solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/Dependent
      [@id = ../Election[@Status='Previous']
                                /Dependent/Dep_ID
     and
       not(@id = ../Election[@Status='Current']
                                /Dependent/Dep_ID)
      ]
```

This selects all `Dependent` elements whose `id` attribute is equal to one of the

```
/*/Election[@Status='Previous']/Dependent/Dep_ID
```

elements and is not equal to any one of the

```
/*/Election[@Status='Current']/Dependent/Dep_ID
```

elements.

**When this XPath expression is evaluated against the provided XML document** (corrected as it was severely malformed):

```
<Employee>
 <Dependent id="100"/>
 <Dependent id="101"/>
 <Dependent id="102"/>
 <Election Status="Current">
  <Dependent>
    <Dep_ID>101</Dep_ID>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent>
    <Dep_ID>102</Dep_ID>
  </Dependent>
 </Election>
  <Election Status="Previous">
  <Dependent>
    <Dep_ID>100</Dep_ID>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent>
    <Dep_ID>103</Dep_ID>
  </Dependent>
  <Dependent>
    <Dep_ID>102</Dep_ID>
  </Dependent>
 </Election>
</Employee>
```

**Exactly the wanted element is selected**:

```
<Dependent id="100"/>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has stated in a comment that he is a beginner and doesn't know how to use this XPath expression.

**Here is one complete code example how to do whatever necessary with all elements that the XPath expression selects** (in this case we just list them):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*/Dependent
      [@id = ../Election[@Status='Previous']
                                /Dependent/Dep_ID
     and
       not(@id = ../Election[@Status='Current']
                                /Dependent/Dep_ID)
      ]">

  <!-- You can do whatever processing is required here  -->
  <!-- For example:                                     -->
  Dependents that were previously elected but are not now:
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Dependents that were previously elected but are not now:
  <Dependent id="100"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE 2**:

The OP clarified further:

> ```
>     <xsl:if test= 
>      "parent::*/Election[(Status='Previous')]
>
>                                  /Dependent/Dep_ID/@id=Depedent_ID"> 
>
>   <!--  DO SOMETHING HERE if above condition is true but this is checking
> ```
>
> only the first "Dependent element.-->
>
> So my question is really: "In the
>   above statement, how can I check
>   whether Dependent_ID is equal to ANY
>   of the parent's
>   Election/Dependent/Dep_ID/@id's?

**The answer**:

This is exactly the condition tested. The condition above evaluates to `true()` exactly when there exists at least one

```
../Election[(Status='Previous')]/Dependent/Dep_ID/@id
```

that is equal to `Depedent_ID` (the `Depedent_ID` child of the current node).

Comment: +1 Good answer. Would it be good other example with keys, perhaps?

Comment: @Alejandro: Keys can provide efficiency in case such test is made more than once. BTW, may I ask you not to upvote me until 0:00 am GMT, as I have reached a max daily rep (293) and any more upvotes for today are ignored ... :)

Comment: @Dimitre: Ja! Congratulations for reaching the daily rep cap!

Comment: @Alejandro: Yep, this has happened on 11 days. On another note, did you try the XPV-2?

Comment: @Dimitre: Not to its depth, but I did. I want to test more expressions involving the sequence data type before sending you my feedback. I like it so far, really good job.

Comment: I think I am following you. But I need this to work in my if condition. I need to do something if this condtion is true.

Comment: All of this is happening in a for loop which loops over each child dependent element of a employee.

Comment: @Richard-N: So, *do* whatever is necessary: `<xsl:apply-templates select="theExpression"/>` or whatever you need to do.

Comment: Dimitre, since I am a beginner I am having trouble understanding how to use your logic in the context that I need. <xsl:if test="parent::*/wd:Benefit_Elections[(wd:Status/@wd:Descriptor='Previous')]/wd:Benefit_Dependents/wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID']=wd:Dep_ID">
I need to modify this exact if statement to check every "wd:Benefit_Dependents" element to see where wd:Benefit_Dependents/wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID']=wd:Dep_ID"? As of now this checks only the first "wd:Benefit_Dependents" element.

Comment: @Richard-N: Sorry, this is not readable. I think the best you can do is to edit your question and to clearly format this code, so that it can be read without the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @Richard-N: I updated my answer and no ir shows (at the very end) with a complete xslt transformation, how to process the selected nodes.

Comment: Dimitre thanks for your patient response. I understood the logic of what you have posted. I also tried to edit my code in the question for better readability but it is still getting the horizontal scroll. Your answer uses Apply-template, but i need this logic as part of my <xsl:if> condition. For some reason I am not getting this to work. It is still checking only the first child "Dependent" element in the parent "Benefit_Elections" element

Comment: @Richard-N: A good advice is to avoid conditionals as much as possible -- in xslt this can be done almost completely. In most cases, if you are using a conditional, this means that you are not using templates properly.

Comment: Dimitre, I have updated my question and modified my code snippet to be more readable. Thanks in advance for your help in understanding this.

Comment: @Richard-N: The unreadable code does not correspond to the provided XML document. In the provided XML document there are no `Benefit_Election` elements, neither are there any namespaces. This is confusing. Please, remove any inconsistencies.

Comment: Dimitre I simplified the XML above because the actual XML is very complicated. I will post the actual XML by trying to make it simpler.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I have edited my XML and the question to make it more clearer. Please let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Richard-N: I have updated my answer to reflect your last question.

Comment: Dimitre, are you saying that my existing code itself should give the right result?

Comment: @Richard-N: The expression does exactly what you say you want it to do -- the problem must be in the surrounding code. You need to read about and understand well comparisons between a value and a node-set and between two node-sets. Your BIG problem is the failure to provide a small and simple *complete* example, that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Dimitre since my original code is higly complicated with so many namespace and specific element names, I tried to simplify it and present it here. But you have given me a lot of insights. One other question is if I need to do the same check but for not equals, is "!=" going to work. As in None of the children Dep_ID's should NOT be equal to the current Dependent_ID?

Comment: I think I got it to work. Thanks Dimitre, your insights have helped me in this issue and previous issues where my questions were already asked by others and answered by you.

Comment: @Richard-N: Never use `$v != $node-set`. Always use: `not($v = $node-set)` . I suspected that this would be a likely cause of your problem, but you never explicitly showed any `!=` code.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue Dimitre. I saw your first reply and changed it and got this to work. I hope it works for all scenarios. You should really write a book on XSLT tips and tricks. I will be the first one to buy it :)